# how to remove the line if it contain the "word"? in python

Tags: python, parsing

I have an input file looks like this

```
test.txt
CAT 396 NUM 59 
X          Y     
4.7642     28.4443    
4.7643     28.3640    
6.2216     29.0680    
6.2217     29.2841    
6.4080     28.6427    
6.6484     28.6484    

CAT 397 NUM 592 
X          Y          
7.0442     23.8320    
7.0994     25.9161    
7.0995     25.1801
```

I only need the X and Y coordinate information.

How would I be able to only get the coordinates?

Comment: Do you parse your file as csv or manually?

Comment: So, where have you got to? Are you able to open the file and move the each line?This is well documented in the python docs. You should show your code-so-far, and not ask for things which are documented a million times on the internet, including in python docs. Look at the partition() function.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
with open('test.txt') as fin :
    lines = fin.readlines()

coords = []
for line in lines :
    try :
        x, y = map( float, line.split())
        coords.append( (x,y) )
    except ValueError:
        pass  # ignore other lines
```

Comment: Thank you!! this is what Im trying to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
line = 'some words'
if 'word' in line:
    # skip/delete the line
```

If the line you want to skip is always first, you can just skip the first line, without checking the words inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readlines()[2:]` to skip first two lines and then parse numbers. For example: like this

```py
lines = open('test.txt').readlines()[2:]
coords = []
for line in lines:
    try:
        coords.append(list(map(float, line.split())), lines))
    except ValueError:
        print(f'ValueError in line: {line}')
print(coords)
```

It returns:

```
[[7.0442, 23.832], [7.0994, 25.9161], [7.0995, 25.1801]]
```

Comment: @lenik Right, it should be handled. Edited my code.